# Board games and card games

Tags: discussion, tags

There exists the tag [board-games](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/board-games) with questions about games using some kind of board.  This can range from [Battleship](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10903/battleship-best-next-move) to [Connect Four](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/561/is-there-any-way-to-trap-my-opponent-on-connect-four) and beyond.  Now, say I want to use a game that just uses cards, like [Uno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uno_%28card_game%29), [Solitaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patience_%28game%29), or [Yu-Gi-Oh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_Trading_Card_Game).  Should they also fall under [board-games](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/board-games), should there be a new tag for [card-games](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/card-games), or should the [cards](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cards) tag be expanded to include non-standard cards?

Comment: I think that in general, card games fall under the broad category of [tag:board games], whether or not they have a board.  Alternatively, we could create a synonym of [tag:board-games] called [tag:tabletop-games].

Comment: Meh, why not just tag 'em [tag:game]?

Comment: @rand fine by me. We can group video games in there

Comment: @randal'thor If we use just "game" we need to make a very good tag-description. It is very likely, people will start using the tag for "game-like" (i.e. "semi-interactive") puzzles. We do NOT want to encourage that. I'm not good at creating tags, but "known-games" maybe?

Comment: I would support the suggestion from @GentlePurpleRain for tabletop-games as puzzles involving boards, cards or some other props are very different from word game puzzles or those relating to computer games.

Answer (score 4):

*Since there seems to be some support, I will make this an answer, so that people can express their agreement or disagreement.*

We should make [board-games](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/board-games) an alias of a newly-created [tabletop-games](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tabletop-games), and make [tabletop-games](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tabletop-games) the primary tag.  It could include board games, card games, and even role-playing games like Dungeons & Dragons.

Comment: Do you plan massive manual retagging, or can this be done by a handwave?

Comment: When we create an alias, all tags are automatically renamed.